# How to auto populate records from another Record Type?

Tags: record-type

I have two Record Types in Opportunities where one is a child of the other. The fields are exact same in both, and the child can be created from within the Parent Opportunity only. When creating the child, I want the fields to be populated from that of the parent, since they are the same. How can I go about doing this in Salesforce?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can auto populate records by creating a Trigger that is launched upon creation of the object record of that Record Type.